# unable to use umlauts/german keyboard layout in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to setup virtualization but am unable to use germany keyboard layout. The letters ö,ä,ü are not recognized when I try to setup the keyboard. The push of those buttons doesn't trigger a reaction in any way.

The host is running ubuntu 14.04 with following hardware specs:

```
Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v2
Hexa-Core Ivy Bridge-E
incl. Hyper-Threading-Technologie
128 GB ECC RAM
2 x 240 GB SATA 6 Gb/s Data Center Series SSD
```

I'm trying to setup the keyboard layout here:

[image]

But there is no response and the time to wait is just running out.

I really don't have any clue on what could couse this weird behaviour. I've been trying to get it running with latest virtualbox and with vmWare Player, but both don't recognize the correct keyboard layout.

When trying to type within the server itself, everything works as expected.

I'm using xfce as desktop, though I would prefer a complete cli solution.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally,

```
   setxkbmap de
```

does it from CLI. Otherwise:

```
    Settings -> Keyboard -> Application shortcuts -> Add -> Command: setxkbmap -layout de (adjust as required) -> OK -> <press the key combination you want>
```

Or again. alternatively,

```
     Applications Menu->Settings->Keyboard
```

And, last, you should install the very convenient xfce4-xkb-plugin package, and add it to your panel for quick changes.

I hope one of these four solves it for you.

EDIT:

> @michael You don't happen to have a USB keyboard, do you?
>
> Yes it is a USB keyboard

This is the root of your problem. USB support is only partial in VirtualBox without Guest additions (aka extension pack): you can use your keyboard, but you cannot change its layout. Install guest additions, then try again changing layout with one of the commands I gave you.

You may try things like: unplug keyboard, then start the VM, once it is up plug in the keyboard. Or use *Devices-> USB* to steal the keyboard, an so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, but still no luck. I can use the letters on the host, but not in the virtual machine. Can I do something there?

Comment: @michael Just for completeness' sake: did you run those commands on the host or on  the guest? They are meant for the guest. Also: guest?

Comment: I tried on both, the host and the guest. On the host the first command line option you suggested ran without error but unfortunately didn't change the odd behavior. On the guest, I'get an error saying (translated) cannot start default display. In this case, the guest as well as the host both are ubuntu 14.04 server installations but I experience the same on ubuntu 15.04 w Gnome desktop as guest os.

Comment: @michael  I get the impression from the error message *cannot start default display* that you have a problem with Xorg. Try *sudo loadkeys de*, in the guest, pls.

Comment: It says "Lade DE" (loading de) but doesn't change it as well. I have just noticed that I get an ö by pressing `shift` and `.` or `,`. If this helps...

Comment: @michael You don't happen to have a USB keyboard, do you?

Comment: Yes it is a USB keyboard.

Comment: @michael pls see the edit in my answer

Comment: Thank you, I'm about to try it. I get an error saying "could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping". I have installed virtualbox-guest-dkms package and dkms, ran apt-get update. It hangs at building the virtualbox guest additions kernel modules saying the headers for the currenct running kernel were not found.

Comment: I do have the guest additions installed and tried turning the vm on and off as you said, but it's still the same error after the command, cannot open display "default display"

Comment: Didn't really solve it, but I have learnt alot thanks to your help! Really apreciate it! Thanks again